# sending the data in Json android Namevaluepair to the php server

Tags: php, android, json

I want to send the contact detail which has name and phone number stored in a array list, for this I am converting this array list to NameValuePairs. Now I would like to send this to PHP server, and save those detail in the database. Just for testing purpose I am currently writing this to file and also returning to android to  check the data. Below is my code:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("xyz.com");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (ContactRetreive cr : al) 
    {
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", cr.name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new     BasicNameValuePair("phone",cr.phone));

}
    Log.i("NameValuePair", nameValuePairs.toString());
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

     response = client.execute(post);
    if (response != null) {
    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
    String a = convertStreamToString(in);
    Log.i("Read from Server", a);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
    }




    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    Log.i("ConvertoStream", "Starting");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Stream Exception",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Log.i("ConvertoStream", "Result:" + total.toString());
    return total.toString();
}
```

Below is my php code block

```
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    $file = fopen("fileOutput1.txt","w");
    echo fwrite($file,$obj);
    foreach ($obj as $item)      
    {                   
       echo $item['name'];
    }


The issue is 
1. It is not writing anything on file that means the data I am passing from the android is not  reading in the php.
2. It is returning the error in the android : Invalid argument supplied to ForEach loop.
```

Please help me I am not able to figure out what is the problem. If you need anything please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

To get `name` and `phone` in php use `$_REQUEST` or `array_values($_POST)` as:

```
$arr_obj = array_values($_POST);
```

Now use `arr_obj` array to get all values posted from android application.

Using `$_REQUEST` :

```
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
```

EDIT : pass Array to php using `BasicNameValuePair` :

```
for (ContactRetreive cr : al) 
{
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name[]", cr.name));
  nameValuePairs.add(new     BasicNameValuePair("phone[]",cr.phone));

}
```

and in PHP get Array using `$_POST` :

```
$arr_name = array($_POST[name]);
$arr_phone = array($_POST[phone]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried this but I am getting Array as output.